# Received corrupt data from Overpass (incomplete polygon) with Overpass API Python wrapper

Tags: python, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'd like to collect forest data on overpass turbo. But my code isn't working properly. 
Here is the first version:

```
import overpass

api = overpass.API()

res = api.get("""
 area[name="Charente-Maritime"]->.searchArea;
 (
 way[landuse=forest](area.searchArea);
 relation[landuse=forest](area.searchArea);;
 way[natural=wood](area.searchArea);
 relation[natural=wood](area.searchArea);
 );
 (._;>;);
 out body;
""")
```

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/3_PROJETS/00_TD/TD7-analyse_spatiale/02_TRAVAIL/forest.py", line 16, in <module>
    """)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\overpass\api.py", line 130, in get
    return self._as_geojson(response["elements"])
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\overpass\api.py", line 214, in _as_geojson
    raise UnknownOverpassError("Received corrupt data from Overpass (incomplete polygon).")
overpass.errors.UnknownOverpassError: Received corrupt data from Overpass (incomplete polygon).
```

I've tried many different syntaxes but none of them have worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has a syntax error, namely an extra semicolon in the following line, which needs to be removed.

```
relation[landuse=forest](area.searchArea);;
```

Before trying any queries in Python, better test them in overpass turbo first, until they work correctly.

Comment: I have the same error message for this request: `rel["name"="Noues de Sienne"](46.081,-5.438,50.121,0.439);` which does work in overpass turbo. Any idea ?

Comment: Looking at the [current code](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/blob/e0b2fcf23818c201aead8809f4adf89564ca656f/overpass/api.py#L214) there is a check that I just do not need. I will work on that.